# WordPressを設置しているサイトで、特定のURLのみルートディレクトリに設置したWordPressの内容を表示できるかどうか知りたい

Tags: php, wordpress

まず、以下のディレクトリ構造になっています。（一部省略しています）

```
sampleA
┣ wordpress （sampleA.com のサイト）
┗ sampleB
　┗ wordpress（sampleA.com/sampleB/ のサイト）
```

sampleAのWordPress内で、「Permalink Manager Lite」というプラグインを利用してURLを変更した投稿を作成しました（sampleA.com/sampleB/hoge/fuga/piyopiyo のようなURLに変更）。

その後、sampleBにWordPressをインストールしたら、上記で設定したURLが見れなくなりました。
これを見られるようにしたいです。
sampleBに設置したWordPressが優先されている？のだと思うのですが、sampleBの方に似たようなURL（sampleA.com/sampleB/hoge/piyopiyo）もあり、明確に何が原因なのかがわかりません。

**試したこと**
sampleB内に、見られるようにしたいURLになるようにディレクトリを追加しました。

```
sampleA
┣ wordpress （sampleA.com のサイト）
┗ sampleB
　┣ wordpress（sampleA.com/sampleB/ のサイト）
　┗ hoge
　　┗ fuga
　　　┗ piyopiyo
```

「piyopiyo」内には、下記のようなindex.phpを設置して、なんとかsampleAのWordPressの投稿を表示できないか試しましたが、できませんでした。

```
<?php
/**
* Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
* wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
*
* @package WordPress
*/

/**
* Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
*
* @var bool
*/
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php';
```

WordPressの機能で、似ているURLから勝手にリダイレクトする機能のせいな気がして
function.phpに以下を追加しましたが、直りませんでした

```
function disable_redirect_canonical( $redirect_url ) {
    if( is_404() ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'disable_redirect_canonical' );
```

Comment: 振り分ける、index.phpをsampleBに置けば出来ます。

Comment: sampleAのページなのだから もっと単純には、piyopiyoフォルダーに、require '/sampleA/wordpress/index.php';するファイルを置いたらどうでしょう？

Comment: yyzさん　やってみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。WordPressの仕様上、どうしようもないのかもしれません。